# BigO Notation of function T(n) = T(n-1)* T(n-2) * T(n-3)

Tags: big-o

```
int f3(int n){
    if (n < 100){
        return 1;
    }
    return n * f3(n-1) * f3(n-2) * f3(n-3);
}
```

What is the bigO notation of the function `f3`, and how do you prove it?

Comment: What do you need to compuete that for?

Comment: Are you **sure** that the time complexity is `T(n) = T(n-1) * T(n-2) * T(n-3)` ?